# Calling QVector in another class error in Qt

Tags: qt, qvector

I recently have a calling `QVector` out of index problem.
To make my question easy to understand, I created two classes, `class A` and `Class B`.
In `Class B`:

```
class B
{
public:
    B();

    QVector<int> mVector;
    void setVector()
    {
        mVector.resize(10);
        qDebug() << "size: " << mVector.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mVector.push_back(i);
        }
        qDebug() << "vector:" << mVector;
    }
};
```

And I called the function and `QVector` in `Class A`:

```
B testingB;
qDebug() << testingB.mVector.size();
testingB.setVector();
qDebug() << testingB.mVector;
qDebug() << testingB.mVector.size();
```

Here is the debug outcome:

```
0
size:  10
vector: QVector(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
QVector(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
20
```

I noticed after that the `QVector` has 20 elements, which should have 10. 
Why would this happen? 
Thanks.

Comment: you can remove `mVector.resize(10);`, or change the push_back to `mVector[i] = i;`

Comment: change `mVector.resize(10);` to `mVector.clear();`

Comment: @JLev I removed it and it worked. Did not expect this. This is some kind of a sample question, my actually problem is call the vector in another class, the program will just terminate and says out of index. I have to try if that works now.

Comment: void QVector::resize(int size) - 
Sets the size of the vector to size. If size is greater than the current size, elements are added to the end; the new elements are initialized with a default-constructed value. If size is less than the current size, elements are removed from the end.

Comment: @JLev Thanks for telling me this then. But since the problem that I mentioned above solved already, should I just delete this post or edit after new question found? Cause I have to test the out of index problem first.

Comment: Don't delete. If you have another question, open a new one.